# How can I store this data in Perl?

Tags: perl, data-structures

Essentially, I made a bunch of Perl code that currently produces output like this:

```
if: 12
for: 26
rof: 26
fi: 27
for: 25
rof: 25
fi: 27
...some more backtracking...
if: 9
fi: 9
for: 26
rof: 26
```

Each line is an event generated by code in a regex in the form: `title: position`.

(I'm not asking about the regex; it perfectly describes a simple CFG I made up. Don't mention anything about it, I just need help storing and then retrieving the data that it's already printing.)

I want `sub mark` to put this data into a data structure. But I'm not sure the best way to do this. I need to be able to retrieve the data in three ways, (with an example of each):

- Title: What events are titled `for`?
- Position: What events fired off at position 12?
- Order: What event was last?

I also want to avoid duplicate entires. If `fi: 27` happens as the fourth and eighth event, I want one entry, with order being an array like `4,8,`.

Please keep in mind that I am very inexperienced with Perl and I would appreciate code examples (explaining how to both store and retrieve using iteration). I know that there seems to be three types of data structures: `$`, `@`, and `%`. I haven't gotten much further than that, because Perl is structured completely different than Java (which I have the most experience in).

Feel free to ask me to clarify anything.

My code is very simple, except for the regex:

```
sub mark{
    my ($title, $position)= @_;
    print "\n";
    print $title;
    print $position;
}

$re = qr{
((?&line))

|(*F)(?:
   (?'line'  (?&if)|(?&for))
   (?'if'    if \((?&exp)*\)\{\s*(?{mark("if: ", pos)})(?&line)*(?{mark("fi: ", pos)})\s*\})
   (?'for'   for\((?&exp)*\)\{\s*(?{mark("for: ",pos)})(?&line)*(?{mark("rof: ",pos)})\s*\})
   (?'eq'    [=])
   (?'exp'   (?&abc)(\s?(?&eq)\s?(?&num)+)?)
   (?'num'   [0-9])
   (?'abc'[a-z])
   (?'space' \s)
)}xm;

# I've been changing the following 'string' to test different stuff
# This is the run that produced the sample data
# 'oops;' doesn't follow the grammar rules, so it shows how the regex may backtrack

'if(true){
  for(i = 5){
  }
  oops;
}' =~ /$re/
     and print "\n\n$1\n\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd create an array to keep the order (@ordered), the following code stores title and position in it. The other two hashes, %by_title and %by_position, just make lookup faster. They only store the index to the @ordered array.

```
use feature qw{ say };
use constant {
    TITLE    => 0,
    POSITION => 1,
};

my (%by_title, %by_position, @ordered);
my $order = 0;
sub mark{
    my ($title, $position)= @_;
    push @{ $by_title{$title} }, $order;
    push @{ $by_position{$position} }, $order;
    push @ordered, [ $title, $position ];
    ++$order;
}

# ...

say "Last: @{ $ordered[-1] }";
say 'Other at the same position:',
    join ', ', map "@{ $ordered[$_] }",
               @{ $by_position{ $ordered[-1][POSITION] } };
say 'Other with the same title: ',
    join ', ', map "@{ $ordered[$_] }",
               @{ $by_title{ $ordered[-1][TITLE] } };
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a hash to store your *titles*, and array references to store the *positions*. That would look something like the following:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'rof: ' => [
                       '26',
                       '25',
                       '24',
                       '23',
                       '26'
                     ],
          'for: ' => [
                       '26',
                       '25',
                       '24',
                       '23',
                       '26'
                     ],
          'fi: ' => [
                      '27',
                      '27',
                      '27',
                      '27',
                      '12',
                      '11',
                      '10',
                      '9'
                    ],
          'if: ' => [
                      '12',
                      '11',
                      '10',
                      '9'
                    ]
        };
```

I produced that by making these changes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %foo;
sub mark{
    my ($title, $position)= @_;

    push @{ $foo{$title} }, $position;
}

# your regex and match here

print Dumper \%foo;
```

To access those, you can iterate using the [`keys` keyword](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) and dereference using `@{ $foo{$key} }` to get to the arrays.

You should read [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html), [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), and you might also be interested in the [`re` pragma's debug mode](https://metacpan.org/pod/re#debug-mode).

Comment: I want to also store the "order" number, which will be 0 the first time `sub mark` runs, then 1... Can I store that too?

Comment: What's the relation of those?

Comment: In my current output, it's equivalent to the line number.

Comment: You could push `[$line, $position]` as the array elements. But I don't see where the line number is coming from.

Comment: Look at my sample output. `if: 12` is the first line... I can probably manage calculating that, in any case.